# LVM in ubuntu - correct way to format PC?

Tags: xubuntu, filesystem, lvm

I have my development machine machine assembled as follows:

I have two hard drives (PVs):

- SSD 240 Gib where is the S.O. (ubuntu 16.04), there is also the boot partition and the swap
- HDD 1 Tb of data, where I have all the information, all the ides and everything mounted so in case of having to format not having to install anything since everything is installed on this hard drive.

In this way, when the equipment was assembled in its day with the help of a co-worker, who no longer works with us, we assembled the file system structure with LVM due to the great power that this provided us if we had to add new ones. disks due to lack of space, the problem is that I do not handle LVM very freely and due to the time that has passed I need to format my computer since I need to install newer versions of Ubuntu, because currently it is giving me a rather bad and slow performance, it eats all the RAM and it doesn't work properly.

That said, at the LVM I have two Volume Groups:

- xubuntu-vg
- xubuntu-data

And I have the following Logical Volume:

- /dev/xubuntu-data/datos perteniente al VG xubuntu-data -- HDD 1 TB
- /dev/xubuntu-vg/root perteneciente al VG xubuntu-vg -- SSD 250 Gib
- /dev/xubuntu-vg-swap_1 perteneciente al VG xubuntu-vg -- SSD 250 Gib

the 1Tb hard drive, I have its logical volume mounted in a system folder to be able to access it within my user, that is, in the following file system path:

- /home/user/Data

What are the correct steps that I must follow to be able to format my computer to continue having my 1Tb hard drive without losing anything?

The following occurs to me and I need to be confirmed if I am right or wrong:

1. Unmount /home/user/Data
2. Install new system in SDD by overwriting and erasing the data from the previous system
3. When installing new S.O. tell me to mount it using LVM
4. Should I re-create the VG xubuntu-data?
5. How do I add the logical data volume again without creating it again and without losing anything?

As you can see I have little real knowledge about all this, please help me as I should in order to format the equipment and continue having my data and the LVM system.

Thank you very much in advance and forgive for the billet!

Comment: Before doing _anything_ else, make a backup to cloud or external drive of things you don't want to lose, then verify the backup matches the source files; then, backup again to a _different_ cloud or external drive and verify that backup matches the source.

Comment: @K7AAY But this does not help me with my problem of how to re-mount the volume group and logical volume after format pc

Comment: What I wrote is not an answer, merely a comment. An answer will follow from someone else.